# Re-Execute Javascript after Ajax Success

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a list of posts on a page that when hovered over reveal a overlay that says 'read more'. At the bottom of the page is an button that runs an ajax function to get more posts. After the ajax has successfully loaded the 'read more' thumbnail overlay no longer reveals on mouse over.

This has to be because the javascript has executed already, and I've loaded more elements into the dom. How can I re-execute the same JS function to allow for the new posts to have the overlay as well?

I've tried re-running my function on ajax success, but it didn't seem to do anything. No error or anything.

**JavaScript**

```
jQuery(".thumboverlay").mouseenter(function() {
                    jQuery(this).stop().animate({
                        opacity: 1
                    });
                });

                    jQuery(".inspiration-project-title").mouseenter(function() {
                        jQuery(this).parent(".brick").find(".thumboverlay").stop().animate({
                            opacity: 1
                        });
                    });

                jQuery(".thumboverlay").mouseleave(function() {
                    jQuery(this).stop().animate({
                        opacity: 0
                    });
                });
                    jQuery(".inspiration-project-title").mouseleave(function() {
                        jQuery(this).parent(".brick").find(".thumboverlay").stop().animate({
                            opacity: 0
                        });
                    });
```

**HTML/PHP**

```
<a href='.get_permalink().'>
   <div class="inspirations-page-featured-image">
     <div class="thumboverlay">
       <p>READ MORE</p>
      </div>'.$printFeaturedImage.'
    </div>
</a>
```

**Ajax**

```
// ajaxLoop.js  
jQuery(function($){  
    var page = 1;  
    var loading = true;  
    var $window = $(window);  
    var $ajaxLoadMoreButton = $("body.blog .ajaxLoadMoreButton");  
    var $content = $("body.blog #container");  
    var load_posts = function(){  
            $.ajax({  
                type       : "GET",  
                data       : {numPosts : 1, pageNumber: page},  
                dataType   : "html",  
                url        : "wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/loopHandler.php", 
                beforeSend : function() {  
                    if(page !=0) {  
                         $ajaxLoadMoreButton.before('<div id="temp_load" style="text-align:center"><img src="wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/images/ajax-loader.gif" /></div>');                          
                    }  
                },  
                success    : function(data){  
                    $data = $(data);  
                    if($data.length){  
                        $data.hide();  
                        $content.isotope('insert', $(data) );
                        $data.fadeIn(500, function(){  
                            $("#temp_load").remove();  
                            loading = false;  
                        });
                    } else {  
                        $("#temp_load").remove();  
                        $ajaxLoadMoreButton.fadeOut().before('<p class="no-more-posts-warning">Sorry, there are currently no more posts to load.</p>');
                    }  
                },  
                error     : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {  
                    $("#temp_load").remove();  
                    alert(jqXHR + " :: " + textStatus + " :: " + errorThrown);  
                }  
        });  
    }  

    $ajaxLoadMoreButton.click(function() {                  
                loading = true;  
                page++;  
                load_posts();   
    });  

});
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your code

Comment: It wouldn't help. The function is 300+ lines long. I just need an understanding of how to refire the function.

Comment: We're not asking for 300 lines of code. We're asking for you to post the essentials of how you're "wiring and firing" things, with a bit of HTML markup to show it off, so we can help you...

Comment: Spend some time at http://jsfiddle.net/ and if you can get your code in there and paste a link to it here on SO, I can almost guarantee you will have a very good answer in less than 5 minutes.

Comment: We need to see what the ajax function is doing that is causing the problem in the first place.

Comment: Are you removing the overlay from the thumbnail at any point?  All you need to do to refire a function is to add parentheses to the end.  Did you mean to ask another question?

Comment: No, its just animating the opacity on hover from 0 to 1, and back on mouseleave

Comment: I see, so at some point during your callback, the animation stops working, right?

Comment: Correct. Once I run the ajax function to pull more posts and they get added to the masonry layout, the new posts don't function as the existing ones. It seems I need to re-run that loop once the elements have been added.

Comment: Is this a CSS3 transition?  It's possible that the css selector that you are using for your transiation is no longer pointing to anything after you add more elements to your page.

Comment: Negative, jQuery.animate({opacity: 0});

Comment: You say you need to re-run this function.  I hate to be so particular, but how do you know this?  Did you run the function in a javascript console to get the effect back?

Comment: Where is `'wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/loopHandler.php'`? is that your HTML/PHP? If so this is an incorrect use of AJAX. Additionally, I would stay away from `var $whatever` in JavaScript. Just do `var whatever`. If you ever reuse your code inside double quotes in PHP that will produce `undefined`.

Comment: @PHPglue I was following http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-loopy-ajax-powered-loops-with-jquery-and-wordpress/ this tutorial

Comment: @jbangerter I run the function on $(document).load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was eventually able to re-fire the function after shifting some things around and adding that section of the overall function to its own individual function.

```
function re_fire_hoverStates() {
   jQuery(".thumboverlay").mouseenter(function() {
                    jQuery(this).stop().animate({
                        opacity: 1
                    });
                });

                    jQuery(".inspiration-project-title").mouseenter(function() {
                        jQuery(this).parent(".brick").find(".thumboverlay").stop().animate({
                            opacity: 1
                        });
                    });

                jQuery(".thumboverlay").mouseleave(function() {
                    jQuery(this).stop().animate({
                        opacity: 0
                    });
                });
                    jQuery(".inspiration-project-title").mouseleave(function() {
                        jQuery(this).parent(".brick").find(".thumboverlay").stop().animate({
                            opacity: 0
                        });
                    });
}
```

Then I did ran the function for the first time on page load, $(document).ready(re_fire_hoverStates);

and then ran the function again, as you had suggested, on Ajax success:

```
// ajaxLoop.js  
jQuery(function($){  
    var page = 1;  
    var loading = true;  
    var $window = $(window);  
    var $ajaxLoadMoreButton = $("body.blog .ajaxLoadMoreButton");  
    var $content = $("body.blog #container");  
    var load_posts = function(){  
            $.ajax({  
                type       : "GET",  
                data       : {numPosts : 1, pageNumber: page},  
                dataType   : "html",  
                url        : "wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/loopHandler.php", 
                beforeSend : function() {  
                    if(page !=0) {  
                         $ajaxLoadMoreButton.before('<div id="temp_load" style="text-align:center"><img src="wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/images/ajax-loader.gif" /></div>');                          
                    }  
                },  
                success    : function(data){  
                    $data = $(data);  
                    if($data.length){  
                        $data.hide();  
                        $content.isotope('insert', $(data) );
                        $data.fadeIn(500, function(){  
                            $("#temp_load").remove();  
                            loading = false;
                            re_fire_hoverStates();  
                        });
                    } else {  
                        $("#temp_load").remove();  
                        $ajaxLoadMoreButton.fadeOut().before('<p class="no-more-posts-warning">Sorry, there are currently no more posts to load.</p>');
                    }  
                },  
                error     : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {  
                    $("#temp_load").remove();  
                    alert(jqXHR + " :: " + textStatus + " :: " + errorThrown);  
                }  
        });  
    }  
    $ajaxLoadMoreButton.click(function() {                  
                loading = true;  
                page++;  
                load_posts();   
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple possible solutions here:

1. Create a new function that will find just the newly added elements and hook up the appropriate event handlers for them and call that function in the success handler of the ajax function after the new elements have been loaded.
2. Use delegated event handling that will work on newly added elements automatically.
3. Change how you're adding new elements.  Don't do things like `elem.innerHTML += htmlstring` because that recreates all existing elements ruining their event handlers.

Which one is better or exactly how to implement any of them depends upon your HTML and what you're doing with your javascript so we can't really advise more specifically without seeing your exact situation (relevant HTML and JS).

Answer (score 1):

As jfriend00 suggested, you can use delegated event handling. In Jquery you can do it like.

```
$( "body" ).delegate( ".ajaxLoadMoreButton", "click", function() {
                  loading = true;  
                page++;  
                load_posts();   
});
```

This will bind the function to all elements matching the selector now and the future (when n new elements are added in the page)
Read more [here](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) about delegate